# Relay vibrates by itself

Tags: relay

I made a circuit using relays to control when to start some motors. Since there were four motors that should be connected, I made four identical circuits.

Testing each individually, they worked. But when you call everyone together, there is a big problem.
One of the relays continuously switches the contacts very fast, without me giving any commands. It starts, vibrates for 4s, stops, waits 15 seconds and does it again.

I'm feeding them all with a source made by me that puts out 5v and 12v. I know that it feeds correctly because it is feeding other circuits besides these. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Circuit below:

[image: Circuit]

The power supply im using is shown below:

[image: Power supply]

I'm using a 30V 5A transformer.

All circuits together:

[image: Circuits]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79242/discussion-on-question-by-natalia-mendes-relay-vibrates-by-itself).

Comment: Is it motor 2? Why is that motor wired up differently from the others?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that when the load on your power supply is large, like when all four relays coils are activated, the current through R1 is causing R1 to drop a large voltage. This drop across R1 will reduce the voltage available to everything that follows, including regulators U1 and U2.

This will cause the regulators to drop out, unable to supply the required voltage to the relay coils to keep them energised. The regulators' dropout voltage specification is 2V, according to the [datasheets](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LM7805.pdf), meaning that you must provide at least \$ 5V + 2V = 7V \$ at the input to the 5V regulator, and \$ 15V + 2V = 17V \$ for the 15V one.

If, for example, each relay coil requires 100mA, at 5V, then their combined current draw will be 400mA which has to come via R1. 400mA through that resistor will drop:

$$ V_{R1} = I_{R1} \times R_1 = 400mA \times 47\Omega = 19V $$

To keep the regulators happy, you need to provide headroom of 2V. Additionally, there are voltage drops across Q2 (at least 1.4V) and R1 (19V), which together mean that your rectified voltage has to be at least:

$$ V_{RECT} = V_{OUT} + V_{DROPOUT} + V_{Q2} + V_{R1} $$

The 5V regulator will need this voltage to be present across C2, at the output of BR1:

$$ V_{RECT} = 5V + 2V + 1.4V + 19V = 27V $$

The 15V regulator will require even more:

$$ V_{RECT} = 15V + 2V + 1.4V + 19V = 37V $$

Note that these figures don't even account for ripple on the recitfied source, which may also cause your regulators to drop out. At 400mA, and with a 4700µF smoothing capacitor, you can expect about a volt or so of ripple, which you must also add to those figures.

One easy solution to is remove R1 altogether, or at least reduce it to some value that won't develop an excessive voltage when the supply is under full load. I presume you included it to reduce power dissipation in the regulators, but I think that 47Ω is just too much here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you mean that when apply a 5 VDC to the coils of the relay it switches too many time for 4 secs and turn back off.
I have encountered the same problem with an over voltage protection circuit, when voltage measured reaches the shutdown predetermined value it oscillates a lot of times for a period of time. I overcome this problem by connecting the input pin of the relay with a capacitor to the ground. it helped by charging the coil with a sufficient voltage for operation. make sure that you choose a capacitor value in the range of 100uF. try this out and tell us how it works.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79243/discussion-on-answer-by-ahmed-m-zahran-relay-vibrates-by-itself).